# Sitecore 8.1 email experience manager - How to create a segmented list？

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am new to Sitecore 8.1 and I am having a problem in creating a segmented list in email experience manager. I have created some new profile into Sitecore, what I want to do is that I can assign some segmentation rules to those profiles and create a segmented list.

As you can see in the 1st image that the right hand side stated "**Matched by this condition: 4**", however, in the section below **"Contacts", it is equal to 0.**

In the 2nd image, those 4 profiles have unique email which can be searched within the Sitecore system (they are juju.shen123, juju.shen444, juju.shen333 and juju.shen111). So why it cannot be displayed while creating the segmented list?

Can someone help me on this? Thanks a lot!

*1st image*

[image]

*2nd image*

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs sometime to process the list. Usually just several minutes. So, have your tea/coffee and contacts will appear.